# SQL Injection Vulnerability found

Tags: sql, security, url, xss, sql-injection

Yesterday i received an email from a guy that our site is vulnerable to SQL injection. The email said:

> I tried some classic SQL injection on
>   your server. This URL contains the
>   result:
>
> http://www.mysite.com/ppreview.php?id=611111161%20and%201=0%20UNION%20all%20SELECT%201,2,3,4,password,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,user_id,70,71%20%20from%20admin--&u=10064&t=users_cars

Note that in the above URL, i do not expose my actual domain and have replaced it with mysite.com.

Can any one explain what above URL means as my site is vulnerable to that sort of url and possibly to your sites too.

How to decode that url, what is happening there?

Comment: Never trust user input.  Never display unfiltered user input.  Please read up on basic website security before you make anymore sites.  Some of your other sites are just as vulnerable.

Comment: i have not worked on this, it is our fellow developer, rather junior, thank fully no site of mine has been vulnerable so far :)

Comment: I spot checked a random one of your sites from your blog and found an XSS exploit in about 3 minutes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you're concatenating that SQL command on the query string into your SQL command.

Presumably your code says something like

```
"select * from preview where ID=" + Request.QueryString["id"]
```

Once you use that QueryString it becomes

```
select * from preview where ID=611111161 and 1=0
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,2,3,4,password,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,user=id,70,71
FROM admin
```

EG: He's made your admin account logins show up on your preview page.

You should always make sure to SQL escape any inputs you get from the user, or even better use parametrized queries and the server will take care of that. Without knowing the language or the type of SQL server I can't really point you in the direction of what code you'd need to do that.

Comment: My code looks like this:

 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $user_id = $_GET['u'];

You see i dont use GET super global variable directly, i first assign them to variables and then use in sql queries, any suggestions please? is this wrong?

Comment: Assigning it to another variable first won't change the final SQL, you're still adding the string to the end of the query. There's actually a nice post about how to use PHP prepared statements at this URL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php - this is the best solution. There's workarounds, like in this case making sure it's a number, but realistically if you use workarounds you'll never close every hole. Using prepared statements 100% protects you cause it tells the server that the field is a value and not executable SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have code that looks like (I don't know php syntax):

`string sql = "select * from mytable where customerid = " + Request.QueryString("id");`

Now, since the guy who mailed you added a lot more than just the id to your page's querystring, your sql statement is going to like like:

`select * from mytable where customerid = 6111111661 and union all the tables that you don't want.`

Always use parameters in your queries and check the user input!
Try to avoid dynamic sql if possible.

Comment: no i dont use vars directly in the sql; i read get vars, assign them to vars and use in query; for example;

$id = $_GET['id'];

$user_id = $_GET['u']

now i use above two vars in my query.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to work like this.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['user']);

if( is_numeric($id) )
{
   mysql_query($query);
}
```

Now your code won't accept an invalid user ID and you won't have issues with SQL injection so long as you sanitize all strings using the method I've outlined.

Comment: to avoid the `is_numeric()` just cast to INT: `$id = (int)$_GET['id'];` when you know that the var has to be an integer.